# Git Branch Deletion (laravel-breeze)

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-remote

if i create branch and make changes in it and then suddenly realized that I don't these changes that I made. At that time if I delete git branch, will it make my project like the old one.

I have not tried anything yet because i am afraid of loosing all the changes.

I have installed Laravel breeze in my project and I have created a seperate branch for it named feature/laravel-breeze-installation.

I want to completely remove laravel breeze vue from my project.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the branch will work it won't affect your other code or your project.

```
git branch -d <branch name>
```

Also, you can revert/restore all the changes in that new branch, it will only affect the changes you have newly made in that branch. Your project will look like the old one.

```
git revert <commit id> - restore to previous commit.
git restore . - restore all changes
```

I hope it will be helpful for you.